# How to get history of the entitlement assignment?

Tags: identity, amazon-iam, oim

I want to get history of revoked entitlements from OIM? since account revoked can be seen from the accounts tab but not the entitlements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of `ENT_ASSIGN_HIST` table.

```
select 
ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.ENT_ASSIGN_HIST_KEY  
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.ENT_LIST_KEY         
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.VALID_FROM_DATE      
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.VALID_TO_DATE        
,usr.usr_login              
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.ACT_KEY              
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.OIU_KEY              
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.OIO_KEY              
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.CREATED_BY           
,ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.CREATED_ON          
from  ENT_ASSIGN_HIST, usr
where ENT_ASSIGN_HIST.usr_key=usr.usr_key
and ent_list_key='<ent_key>';
```